# Flip coin simulation with R programming

Tags: r, coin-flipping

I'm new to R and I'm doing a practice question.
Simulate rolling a fair coin 200 times, then plot a histogram of the data.
I did:

```
outcomes      <- c("heads", "tails")
sim_fair_coin <- sample(outcomes, size = 200, replace = TRUE)
hist(table(sim_fair_coin))
```

It does give me a histogram, but I think I expect a more intuitive histogram. With the X-axis shows "heads" or "tails"; and the Y-axis shows how many times I got for "heads" and "tails".
I believe there is a way to accomplish this in R. Can someone tell me more about it please?

Comment: You are probably looking for a bar plot: `barplot(table(sim_fair_coin))`

Comment: @Sumedh This is the correct answer. I would suggest to make the plot a little nicer then move it to an answer and collect your points. :)

Comment: @Hack-R, I was under the assumption that this question would probably be deleted or something like that. Anyway, I guess I am late :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ggplot2` package.

```
x <- as.data.frame(sim_fair_coin)
ggplot(x, aes(factor(sim_fair_coin))) + geom_bar(width=.5)
```